# Lumia 720 Update problem

Tags: lumia, update

I am new user for Lumia 720 WP When i try to Update my phone, could see a blank status of updating message remains for a long while.

How do i resolve this issue? Is it a Device defect?

[image]

Thanks..

Comment: Where you connected to WiFi at the time?

Comment: Yes it was connected with wifi..

Comment: Have you restarted the phone? what is the current software version (Settings > About)?

Comment: change ur region and language to US. then, it will work immediately.

Answer (score -1):

you need phone recovery tool to update lumia 720 as its was nokia brand phone and now new lumai phone comes under Microsoft labels .you can get the tool online in Microsoft web site.enjoy

Comment: Could you edit your question and add a link to the recovery tool that you mentioned?